# how can I pass the Reference of an arraylist to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

how can I pass the Reference  of an arraylist to an array?

I have an Arraylist but the method constraints that I should return an array and I should return an array with the same reference as the one given to me in the signature of the method,  and I can not simply not use The ArrayList because that would require a lot of changes in the code. so is there a quick way to do it??

```
public Skill[] getSkills() {
  if (skills.size() == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  Skill[] result = new Skill[skills.size()];
  result = skills.toArray(result);
  return result;
}

public void setSkills(Skill[] skills) {
  if (skills.length != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
      this.skills.add(i, skills[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

the Junit test is:

```
@Test(timeout = 1000)
public void testGetSkills() {
  instance.setSkills(skills);
  assertSame("The returned skill array should be the same", instance.getSkills(), skills);
}
```

Comment: can you post some code of your problem?

Comment: Could you add what you have done?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I pass the Reference of an arraylist to an array?

```
public T[] method() {
List<T> list=....; 
 //other ops
return list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
}
```

[**List#toArray(T..a)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)  method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs.

Answer (score 1):

consider Ur method have parameter as follows

```
public Array method (Array signature)
{
ArrayList<object> ArrayList = new ArrayList<object>();

foreach(object test in ArrayList )
{
 if(test == signature)
{
    return test
}  
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have an Arraylist but the method constraints that I should return an array

Can you not just do:

```
return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Assuming your `ArrayList` is of Strings here of course - replace `String` with whatever type is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can return list.toArray( [list.size()]);